# The child component appears in the ProtectedRoute for some time

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom, redux-toolkit

I have implemented authorization in React. I want the user to not be able to go to other pages of the application without authorization. I created the following component.

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../hooks/use-auth";

interface ProtectedRouteProps {
  children: ReactNode,
}

export const ProtectedRoute: React.FC<ProtectedRouteProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const { isAuth } = useAuth();
  
  return !isAuth ? <Navigate to="/login" replace /> : <>{children}</>;
};
```

However, when going to authorization page in a reverse redirect, the child component is rendered for a few milliseconds. How to fix it?

```
<Route 
  path="/kanban" 
  element={
    <ProtectedRoute>
      <KanbanPage />
    </ProtectedRoute>
  }
/>
```

```js
import { RootState, useAppSelector } from "../store";
        
export function useAuth() {
  const { email, token, id } = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state.user);
        
  return {
    isAuth: !!email,
    email,
    token,
    id,
  }
}
```

Auth logic

```js
const onSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const auth = getAuth();
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then(({ user }) => {
      dispatch(setUser({
        email: user.email,
        id: user.uid,
        token: user.refreshToken,
      }));
      setOpenSnackbar(true);
      setTimeout(() => navigate('/kanban'), 2000)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

redux:

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    
const initialState = {
  email: null,
  token: null,
  id: null
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUser(state, action) {
      state.email = action.payload.email;
      state.token = action.payload.token;
      state.id = action.payload.id;
    },
    removeUser(state) {
      state.email = null;
      state.token = null;
      state.id = null;
    }
  }
});

export const { setUser, removeUser } = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: I think your useAuth is returning True first, then False. Please share useAuth.

Comment: @Kamran added my code

Comment: Your issue is that when user is not set, and you try to access protected page, the page is rendered for some ms and then moved to login page, is that right?

Comment: The `isAuth` is incorrectly returning `true` or `false` when the auth status isn't known yet. Can you [edit] to include the Redux code so we can see the actions and reducers that handle the authentication state? See [mcve].

Comment: @Kamran Yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

you have to enter the isAuth to useMemo and only when the isAuth will changed  the component rerendered.

Answer (score 0):

The `isAuth` is incorrectly returning `true` or `false` when the auth status isn't known yet.

Update the `setUser` reducer to set an `isAuth` state value instead of coercing the `email` value to a boolean.

```js
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    isAuth: undefined, // <-- initially undefined
    email: "",
    token: "",
    id: "",
  },
  reducer: {
    setUser: (state, action) => {
      const { email, token, id } = action.payload;
      state.isAuth = !!email; // <-- set computed isAuth here
      state.email = email;
      state.token = token;
      state.id = id;
    },
    removeUser: (state) => {
      state.isAuth = false;
      state.email = null;
      state.token = null;
      state.id = null;
    }
  },
});
```

Update `ProtectedRoute` to conditionally render null or a loading indicator when the `isAuth` value isn't set/determined yet.

```js
export function useAuth() {
  const { isAuth, email, token, id } = useAppSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.user
  );
    
  return { isAuth, email, token, id };
}
```

```
export const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const { isAuth } = useAuth();

  if (isAuth === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  
  return isAuth
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};
```

```
<Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
  <Route path="/kanban" element={<KanbanPage />} />
  ... other protected routes ...
</Route>
```

Comment: I tried your method, but the problem remains

Comment: @Никита Then it's likely you missed something or there's more to the issue than has been shared so far. Can you create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the routing/rendering issue that we could inspect live?